# measure of a degenerate Gaussian distribution

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, gaussian, lebesgue-measure

I want to do computations with a degenerate Gaussian measure, but I do not know how to represent it
in a close form.

After starting with a Gaussian random variable and restricting it to a condition, I end up with
a Gaussian random variable $X\sim \mathcal N(0, \Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is singular (say I end up with one dimension less). I guess, that one can make computations with density
$$    \begin{align}
        \pi(x) &= \frac{1}{\left(2\pi^{c-1} {|\Sigma|}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \exp
        \left( -\frac 1 2 x^\intercal \Sigma^- x\right),
    \end{align}
$$
where $|\Sigma|$, $\Sigma^-$ denote the generalized determinant and generalized inverse respectively. What I have understand so far, is that $\pi$ is a density function but with respect to a degenerate measure (a sort of restriction of the Lebesgue measure). I tried working with the dicomposition theory, but didn't get any satisfactory solution so far.
Since I can calculate the kernel of $\Sigma$, after
doing a transformation with respect to the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $\Sigma$, I can become
another density $\widetilde \pi$ which ignores the first component. My guess would be
that I can integrate then with respect to the Lebesgue measure in one dimension less.
Does it make sense?

The main questions would be: With respect to which measure is this distribution defined and do it exist a close form for this measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\Si\Sigma\newcommand\si\sigma\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}$
The calculations can be done as follows.

Consider the spectral decomposition of $\Si$:
\begin{equation}
    \Si=QDQ^T,\tag{0}
\end{equation}
where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix $n\times n$ matrix and $D$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\si_1^2>0,\dots,\si_k^2>0,0,\dots,0$, so that $k$ is the rank of $\Si$. Let $Y:=Q^TX$, so that $X=QY$ and $Y=(Y_1,\dots,Y_k,0,\dots,0)\sim N(0,D)$. So, for any Borel-measurable function $g\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ such that $Eg(X)$ exists, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    Eg(X)&=Eg(Q[Y_1,\dots,Y_k,0,\dots,0]^T) \\ 
&=\int_{\mathbb R^k}g(Q[y_1,\dots,y_k,0,\dots,0]^T) \\
&\times f_{\si_1}(y_1)\cdots f_{\si_k}(y_k)dy_1\cdots dy_k,
\end{aligned}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $f_\si$ is the pdf of $N(0,\si^2)$.

Now you can compute the probabilities for $X$ as follows:
$$P(X\in B)=E1(X\in B),$$
where $B$ is any Borel subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

---

For an illustration, here is a Mathematica notebook with the calculation of the probability $P(X_1>X_2+1)$ given $(X_1,X_2)\sim N\left((0,0),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right)$:

[image]

---

As you insist on writing the expectation $Eg(X)$ as an integral with respect to the Lebesgue measure on the support of the distribution of $X$, here it is.

Note that the support of the distribution of $X$ is the range(=column space) $\Si\R^n$ of $\Si$, which is the same as the range $q\R^k$ of $q$, where $q$ is the map
\begin{equation*}
    \R^k\ni z=(z_1,\dots,z_k)\mapsto qz:=QJz\in q\R^k=\Si\R^n
\end{equation*}
and, in turn, $J$ is the map
\begin{equation*}
    \R^k\ni z=(z_1,\dots,z_k)\mapsto Jz:=(z_1,\dots,z_k,0,\dots,0)\in\R^n. 
\end{equation*}
The equality $\Si\R^n=q\R^k$ follows because, in view of (0), the range $\Si\R^n$ of $\Si$ is the same as that of $QD^{1/2}$, which is the same as that of $q$ (since the range of $D^{1/2}$ is the same as that of $J$). Here, we identify matrices with the corresponding linear transformations.

In view of (1),
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    Eg(X)&=\int_{\R^k}g(qz)\nu(dz)
    =\int_{\Si\R^n}g(x)\mu(dx),
\end{aligned}
\tag{2}
\end{equation*}
where $\nu(dz):=\pi(z)\la_k(dz)$, $\pi(z):=f_{\si_1}(z_1)\cdots f_{\si_k}(z_k)$, $\la_k(dz)$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\R^k$, and $\mu(dx):=\nu(q^{-1}(dx))=\pi(q^{-1}(x))\la_k(q^{-1}(dx))$.

Since the map $q$ is an isometry, for the Lebesgue measure $\la_{\Si\R^n}$ over $\Si\R^n$ we have $\la_{\Si\R^n}(dx)=\la_k(q^{-1}(dx))$. So, by (2),
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    Eg(X)&=\int_{\Si\R^n}g(x)\pi(q^{-1}(x))\la_{\Si\R^n}(dx). 
\end{aligned}
\tag{3}
\end{equation*}
In particular, letting $g:=1_B$ for any Borel set $B\subseteq\Si\R^n$, we get
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    P(X\in B)&=\int_B \pi(q^{-1}(x))\la_{\Si\R^n}(dx). 
\end{aligned}
\tag{3a}
\end{equation*}

I think formulas (3) and, in particular, (3a) are completely useless, though -- because you will actually **compute** $Eg(X)$ and $P(X\in B)$ (as in the above Mathematica notebook) by formula (1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  This is what I guessed, when I meant using $\widetilde \pi$, since
$$ \widetilde \pi(y) = f_{\sigma 1} (y_1) \cdots f_{\sigma k}(y_k). $$ Thus, $\widetilde \pi$ can be seen as the density function of  $Q^\intercal X \sim \mathcal N (0,D)$ "in a sense" (avoiding the zero components).  But, is there a way to express the density of $X$ (i.e., $\pi$ in my question) w.r.t. a (degenerate) measure?, i.e., 
$$P(X\in B) = \int \pi(x) d?, $$ 
The reason for this need, is that I want to apply later transformations, and applying already one, makes everything more confusing.

Comment: @SkullSoul : I have to teach now. I'll respond to this later.

Comment: @SkullSoul : I have added the measure stuff.

Comment: @losifPinelis: Thanks a lot for the effort!! I understand what you mean and that your explanation help for numerical computations. But my question was slightly different as your answer. I formulate again with the same terminology:  Given is a positiv-SEMI definite matrix $\Sigma$, $\mu = 0$ and 
$$ \pi(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi^{c-1} |\Sigma| } e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^T \Sigma^- x},$$
$|\Sigma|, \Sigma^-$ are generalized determinant and inverse.
Is there a way to write the degenerate measure $\zeta$ in a close form, i.e. if
$$Pr(X \in B) = \int_B \pi(x) d\zeta,$$ then $$\zeta = ?$$

Comment: @SkullSoul : Of course, the probabilities $P(X\in B)$ can be expressed as integrals with respect to the Lebesgue measure on the support of the distribution of $X$. I have now added the corresponding formula (3a) -- which is a particular case of the previously given formula (3). Formula (3a) has the correct expression, $\pi(q^{-1}(\cdot))$, for the density of the distribution of $X$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on the support of the distribution of $X$.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Your expression for $\pi$ cannot be correct in general; for one thing, $|\Sigma|$ may be $0$. On the other hand, as I said, you don't need this measure stuff in this kind of problems at all. If you want later to apply more transformations, then just use (1) for the updated $\Sigma$ and its spectral decomposition. BTW, I am wondering: have you taken a standard course on (measure-theory-based) probability?

Comment: thanks again! Sadly I feel, that you don't get that my question is about, how to write the degenerate measure in a close form (if possible), because I want to keep the "density function". I guess this degenerate measure cannot be the image measure of the Lebesgue measure under a transformation. Please consider my question again (last time): I have $X \sim \mathcal N(0, \Sigma)$. Sigma is only positiv semi-definit. I consider the generalized inverse $\Sigma^-$ and generalized determinant $|\Sigma|$ (which cannot (!) be zero), because I ignore the 0 eigenvalues.

Comment: I wish to write $$ Pr(X \in A) = \int_A f_1(x) d\zeta \quad (A1)$$ where 
$$ f_1(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi^{c-1} |\Sigma|} e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^\intercal \Sigma^- x}. $$ I wish to work with $f_1$, and wonder how the measure $\zeta$ looks like.  If you apply a transformation as you mention above $Y = Q^\intercal X$, then we are just applying a transformation formula
$$ \int_{A} f_1 Q^\intercal Q d\zeta = \int_{Q A} f_2(x) d Q(\zeta)$$ and $f_2= f_{\sigma_1} * \dots f_{\sigma_k}$ (with your not. as in (1) )(since the cov. matrix is now diagonal) $Q \zeta=$ image measure of $\zeta$ under $Q$ (as oper.)

Comment: My intuition is that the image measure $Q \zeta $ can be written as the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R^{k}$. Ok. I agree, working with the spectral decomposition, makes everything nicer, because you are working with $f_2 = f_1 \circ Q^\intercal = f_{\sigma_1} * \dots * f_{\sigma_k}$ (of course $f_{\sigma_i}$ consider only the components of the Eigenvectors that don't have EV 0). But, I would like to work with $f_1$ and $\zeta$ (if possible).

Comment: @SkullSoul : If you want to know what the measure $\zeta$ is such that $P(X\in A)=\int_A f_1(x)\zeta(dx)$ for all Borel sets $A\subseteq\Sigma\mathbb R^n$, just look at formula (3a) and equate your $f_1(x)\zeta(dx)$ with $\pi(q^{-1}(x))\lambda_{\Sigma\mathbb R^n}(dx)$ in (3a), to get $\zeta(dx)=\dfrac{\pi(q^{-1}(x))}{f_1(x)}\,\lambda_{\Sigma\mathbb R^n}(dx)$. This is the only measure $\zeta$ with your desired property, because the identity $P(X\in A)=\int_A f_1(x)\zeta(dx)$ for all Borel sets $A\subseteq\Sigma\mathbb R^n$ uniquely determines the measure $\zeta$.

Comment: @losifPinelis , could you cite some reference for the  expressions, e.g. (1) ?

Comment: @SkullSoul : I don't think that there are references for this.